# How to run SCORM complainant packages in localhost?

Tags: scorm

Getting error on localhost:

An error has occurred: Error - unable to acquire LMS API, content may not play properly and results may not be recorded. Please contact technical support. Press 'OK' to view debug information to send to technical support.

Comment: You cant run a SCORM Compliant course in localhost without a LMS support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SCORM packages will only run within the context of an LMS.  That error is saying that the JavaScript API (which should be provided by the LMS) could not be found.

I would guess that you are just running the content directly, in which case there is no LMS present.

Either get a copy of your LMS set up locally, and run the content via that (as you would do in the live LMS) or upload the content to another LMS (http://cloud.scorm.com/, for example).

An alternative is to use a standalone SCORM player, which mimics the functionality of an LMS by providing an API, but it's not actually persisting the data anywhere.  I've used one a while ago, but I can't remember its name (sorry!).  If that's something you would find useful, you should be able to find one somewhere.